# Moveing from Sqlite3 to PostgreSQL(ror 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, rake

I'm looking forward to change the develeop and prodoction  databses in order to be able to migrate to heroku. 
I fallowed [this link](http://xtremekforever.blogspot.ro/2011/05/setup-rails-project-with-postgresql-on.html) step by step everything went ok, I restarted the server `rails s` while my postgresql was started and I got this error

```
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Tasks#main

Showing /home/bogdan/ex/bored/app/views/tasks/_rand_task.html.erb where line #3 raised:

PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "tasks" does not exist
LINE 4:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"tasks"'::regclass
                                        ^
:             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
              FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
             WHERE a.attrelid = '"tasks"'::regclass
               AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
             ORDER BY a.attnum
```

Since  that is the first call of an object, I'm wandering  shouyld i migrate or do anyhting else in order to get my `pg` working (sorry if the question is dummiesh)

Comment: Did you run `rake db:create:all` to create your new Postgres databases?

Comment: just now discovered a new tutorial which was saying that... Thanks a bunch that was the only problem :<

Comment: You're welcome.  I'll put that as the answer to close out this question.

Comment: Thanks again. Since rails comunity ain't really vaste i appreciate when I get an useful answere :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `rake db:create:all` to create your new Postgres databases.